I just installed guix on a virtual machine.. how can I run sshd?
I am a first time guix user and need assistance doing this basic thing.
I did guix pull and guix install openssh but the sshd command is not there. After typing guix pull and guix install openssh, I have now the openssh package but the sshd command is not there. After reading this excerpt it seems I need to edit a configuration, however this enviroment was just the qemu image of guix. And /etc/config.scm is an empty file. So there is nothing to edit. How can I run the sshd service, after booting in guix?

So I discovered many binaries are in guix, just hidden from the user, you can call sshd from guix shell openssh, just that it can't be seen from outside.
My attempt:
# This is messy and not really a guix way, but for now best I can do
sudo mkdir -p /etc/ssh
sudo tee /etc/ssh/sshd_config <<-EOF
PermitRootLogin yes
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
EOF
sudo groupadd sshd
sudo useradd -g sshd sshd
sudo ssh-keygen -A
sudo guix shell openssh -- sh -c '"$(which sshd)"'

Edit: What happens when you normally try it.
guest@gnu ~$ sshd
bash: sshd: command not found
guest@gnu ~$ guix shell openssh -- sh -c sshd
sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path
guest@gnu ~$ guix shell openssh -- sh -c $(which sshd)
which: no sshd in (/run/setuid-programs:/home/guest/.config/guix/current/bin:/home/guest/.guix-profile/bin:/run/current-system/profile/bin:/run/current-system/profile/sbin)
sh: -c: option requires an argument
guest@gnu ~$ guix shell openssh -- sh -c "$(which sshd)"
which: no sshd in (/run/setuid-programs:/home/guest/.config/guix/current/bin:/home/guest/.guix-profile/bin:/run/current-system/profile/bin:/run/current-system/profile/sbin)
guest@gnu ~$ guix shell openssh -- sh -c '"$(which sshd)"'
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied
guest@gnu ~$ sudo guix shell openssh -- sh -c '"$(which sshd)"'
guest@gnu ~$ 

